# Unable to receive moengage push notifications

Tags: flutter, dart, moengage

I have go through the documentation of [moengage flutter](https://docs.moengage.com/docs/flutter-sdk-integration) but unable to receive the notifications
i have added fcm keys in dashboard also. Below in my implementation
When i am sending notification through fcm are working fine
basically we have 2 modes of flutter apk prod and debug and i am working on debug i have added debug package name in moengage dashboard.
when i create campaign and send a push to android all users its not working. Please help here

Application.kt class

```
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant


import com.moengage.core.LogLevel
import com.moengage.core.MoEngage
import com.moengage.core.MoEngage.Builder
import com.moengage.core.config.FcmConfig
import com.moengage.core.config.LogConfig
import com.moengage.core.config.MiPushConfig
import com.moengage.core.config.PushKitConfig
import com.moengage.core.config.NotificationConfig
import com.moengage.flutter.MoEInitializer
import com.moengage.pushbase.MoEPushHelper
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val moEngage = MoEngage.Builder(this, "hereIHaveAddedTheKey")
                .build()
        MoEngage.initialise(moEngage)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        if (registry == null) return
    }
}
```

Build.gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    /// ---- moengage sdk start----
    implementation("com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:11.2.00")
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.2.0")
    implementation("com.moengage:hms-pushkit:2.0.01")
    implementation("com.moengage:rich-notification:2.2.00")
    implementation("androidx.core:core:1.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0")
    /// --- end ----
}
```

app-> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is flutter moengage initialization

```
 final MoEngageFlutter _moengagePlugin = MoEngageFlutter();

  void initialise() {
    _moengagePlugin.initialise();
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialise();
  }
```

mainefestFile

```
<service android:name="com.moengage.firebase.MoEFireBaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

You to add the required metadata for showing push notification and also pass the payload to the SDK using provided API. Refer to the documentation here - https://docs.moengage.com/docs/push-configuration

Comment: configureNotificationMetaData(NotificationConfig(R.drawable.small_icon, R.drawable.large_icon, R.color.notiColor, null, true, isBuildingBackStackEnabled = false, isLargeIconDisplayEnabled = true)

here actually i am having compiling error for small_icon and large_icon
how do i fix them

Comment: i have already added the firebase receiver in manifest file 
please see the the updated question above

Comment: I am guessing you are referring to the example we have in the repository. If you see we have placeholder small and large icons in the drawable folder of the application. You can replace the names with the actual icon names.
In case you are not sure how to proceed on this feel free to write to us at support@moengage.com and our team will help you out.

Comment: okay trying these things and will let you know
thank you sir

Comment: You have added the Mixpanel receiver which will not understand MoEngage SDK's payload. You need to either pass the payload to the SDK via the provided API in the documentation or use MoEngage's receiver. Updated the links in the answer based on the question edit.

Comment: can you tell me 1 thing how do moengage know where it needs to send notification like in prod app or debug app

Comment: Please drop an email to the above mentioned e-mail id and our team will help you out.